# Cannot figure out code execution order

Tags: java, instance, language-concepts

I have the following code.

```
class X {
    X(){
        super();
        System.out.println("X()");
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    Y(){
        super();
        System.out.println("Y()");
    }
}

class Z extends Y {
    Z(){
        super();
        System.out.println("Z()");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Z z1 = new Z();
    }
}
```

And I get the output

```
X()
Y()
Z()
```

All fine. It's the way, it's supposed to be. And when I make an static object of X() in the class Z like follows

```
class X {
    X(){
        super();
        System.out.println("X()");
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    Y(){
        super();
        System.out.println("Y()");
    }
}

class Z extends Y {
    static X x1 = new X();
    Z(){
        super();
        System.out.println("Z()");
    }   

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Z z1 = new Z();
    }
}

X()
X()
Y()
Z()
```

The output is ok because the static instances are loaded to the RAM at first. But when I make the static object instance like this

```
X x1 = new X();
```

I get the following output

```
X()
Y()
X()
Z()
```

Which really confuses me. As for my knowledge, I should get the following output

```
X()
Y()
Z()
X()
```

At the first the Z object will be instantiated and the X object should be instantiated at last. In this case, it instantiates at third. Why is that? Is there any special concept that applies here?

Comment: `X x1 = new X();` it's not static anymore, right?

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik Yes But I what I wanna know is why does the instance object executes at third? instead of last?

Comment: It's initialized before calling the constructor of `Z`.

Comment: In the linked answer, you can see that step 4 (run the instance variable initializers) comes after invoking the superconstructor and before running the rest of the constructor.